# Can I solve $x=\ln(4-x^2)$ without the use of a graphing calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

My textbook tells me to solve $x= \ln(4-x^2)$ with a graphing calculator, but when solving it manually, everything I try always ends on a dead end.

One of my approaches was this:

\begin{align}
x &= \ln(4-x^2) \\
e^x &= 4-x^2 \\
\log(e^x) &= \log(4-x^2) \\
\log(e^x)-\log(4-x^2) &= 0 \\
\log\left(\frac{e^x}{4-x^2}\right) &= 0 \\
\frac{e^x}{4-x^2} &= \color{red} 1
\end{align}

No Solution.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Don't await an **exact** solution for this kind of equation with a polynomial LHS and a "transcendental" RHS. This is why your textbook wants you to solve it by approximation methods.

Comment: actually 2 solutions. btw $\ln x=0$ does not imply $x=0$

Comment: You do realize line 2 and line 6 are contradictory?  Because of MANMAID's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said, you cannot get an anytical solution and you need to resort to numerical methods.

As you probably noticed, the solution is quite close to $x=1$; so, for example, you could use $$x_{n+1}=\log(4-x_n^2)$$ Starting with $x_0=1$, you will get as iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 1 & 1.00000\\
 2 & 1.09861 \\
 3 & 1.02713 \\
 4 & 1.08011 \\
 5 & 1.04147 \\
 6 & 1.06999 \\
 7 & 1.04912 \\
 8 & 1.06449 \\
 9 & 1.05322 \\
 10 & 1.06151
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is not very nice since oscillating (you would need to repeat the process about $30$ times for six correct significant figures).

Better would be a Taylor expansion built around $x=1$
$$x-\log(4-x^2)=(1-\log (3))+\frac{5}{3} (x-1)+\frac{5}{9} (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ Using the first term would give, as estimate,
$$(1-\log (3))+\frac{5}{3} (x-1)=0 \implies x=\frac{1}{5} (2+3 \log (3))\approx 1.05917$$ Adding the quadratic  term $$x=\frac{3}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{5} (1+4 \log (3))}-\frac{1}{2}\approx 1.05804$$

For sure, Newton method will do a perfect job for any accuracy; starting with $x_0=1$, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1.0000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 1.0591673732008658148 \\
 2 & 1.0580068807921076662 \\
 3 & 1.0580064010907181542 \\
 4 & 1.0580064010906363086
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.